# What does "enable optimizations" do?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

For both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS projects, there is a checkbox under "Compiler" titled "Enable Optimizations". The meaning is clear enough, but exactly what optimizations are those? For IOS, for example, there is already a separate option for enabling the optimizing LLVM compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# compiler (either Mono's `mcs` on the Mac or Microsoft's `csc` on Windows) can emit *somewhat* better IL when this option is selected.

YMMV but, in general, this means some extra time to compile your source code and the IL might be harder to read (if you decompile it) and sometime debug. In most cases the generated code will be identical.

Because of this the default option is, normally, to use **Enable Optimizations** only for **release** builds (and not for **debug** builds).

OTOH this has nothing to do with the JIT (or AOT or LLVM) optimizations that will be done later at runtime (for Xamarin.Android) or at native compilation (for Xamarin.iOS).